# Proving the continuity of $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\bigl(\exp\bigl(-\frac{x^2}{n}\bigr)-1\bigr)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I would like to prove the continuity of $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\bigl(\exp\bigl(-\frac{x^2}{n}\bigr)-1\bigr)$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

The most obvious way to go about this is to first state that $\left\lvert \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)-1\right\rvert \leq \frac{x^2}{n} $.

This then implies that $\left\lvert\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)-1\right)\right\rvert \leq \frac{x^2}{n^{3/2}} $.

Ideally then we would use a Weierstrass $M$-test to find a convergent majorant series as this would then grant us the continuity of $f(x)$ as desired. However the issue that I am finding is that the majorant series may NOT depend on $x$. Now I *think* I have found a way around this issue, but suddenly it feels like I am in fact merely showing regular convergence and *not* uniform convergence. My idea is as follows:

Consider the restriction of $f(x)$ onto the interval $M$ with $x\in M$ and $M=]-x_0,x_0[$

Then the series  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_0^2}{n^{3/2}}$  is a convergent majorant series for $f(x)$ restricted to $M$ and as such we have uniform convergence on the interval $M$ and thus specially uniform convergence in the point $x$ since $x\in M$, which then implies continuity in $x$. But we may generate this restriction for *any* $x$ that we desire so we are able to prove continuity in any general $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and thus we must have that $f(x)$ is continuous in all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Is this proof correct? I have to admit that when I do my restriction and start proving continuity for a single point at a time it feels like I am no longer using uniform convergence, so I'm a little iffy on whether the math here holds up. I would deeply appreciate some comments on whether or not I've made any mistakes!

Comment: For the sake of clarity you should say how your $x_0$ is chosen. To prove continuity at  a point $x$ you can take $x_o=1+|x|$ so that $x$ lies in $(-x_0,x_0)$ and use uniform convergence on $[-x_0,x_0]$ to finish the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Your proof may be harnessed by a couple of ways:

1. As pointed out by @Kavi Rama Murthy, for each given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, you may want to specify the interval on which the Weierstrass $M$-test will be applied. For this purpose, you may pick any bounded interval that contains $x$ as an interior point, such as $(x_0 - 1, x_0 + 1)$.
2. Alternatively, you may apply Pasting Lemma:

   > **Pasting Lemma.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and let $\{ A_{i} \}_{i \in I}$ be an arbitrary family of open sets. If a function $f : \bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \to Y$ is continuous on each $A_i$, $i \in I$, then $f$ itself is also continuous.

   If you are not familiar with point-set topology, you may regard both $X$ and $Y$ in the above lemma as $\mathbb{R}$. Its proof is quite straightforward.

   Now if we choose the index set as $I = (0, \infty)$ and let $A_i = (-i, i)$ for each $i \in I$, then your argument shows the function $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-1/2}(e^{-x^2/n}-1)$ is continuous on each interval $A_i$, and so, $f$ is continuous on all of $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i=\bigcup_{i>0}(-i,i)=\mathbb{R}$.

Finally, let me conclude by proving the following claim:

> **Claim.** The defining sum for $f(x)$ does converge uniformly on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

*Proof.* By the local uniform convergence again, we find that $f$ is term-wise differentiable with

$$ f'(x) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2x}{n^{3/2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{n}}. $$

Now define $g : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$ g(t) = \begin{cases} 2t^{-3/2}e^{-1/t}, & t > 0; \\ 0, & t = 0. \end{cases} $$

Then $g$ is continuous, non-negative, monotone-increasing on $[0, \frac{2}{3}]$, and monotone-decreasing on $[\frac{2}{3}, \infty)$. Using this, it is not hard to prove that

$$ -f'(x)
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g\left(\frac{n}{x^2}\right)\frac{1}{x^2}
\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} \int_{0}^{\infty} g(t) \, \mathrm{d}t
= 2\sqrt{\pi}. $$

Then by the L'Hospital's Rule,

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}
= \lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)
= - 2\sqrt{\pi}. $$

In particular, $f(x)$ is unbounded from below. Since each partial sum of $f(x)$ is bounded on all of $\mathbb{R}$, the convergence cannot be uniform.